# Krull's intersection theorem and closedness of submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

In the book "Formal and rigid geometry" by Bosch, page 70, there is a claim that if $\varphi :\operatorname{Sp}A\to \operatorname{Sp}A^{\prime}$ is a map of affinoid spaces, $x\in \operatorname{Sp}A^{\prime}$ and $m_x\subset A^{\prime}$ and $m_{\varphi(x)}\subset A$ the corresponding maximal ideals, then for the induced morphism $\varphi^{*}_{m_x}:A_{m_{\varphi(x)}}\to A^{\prime}_{m_x}$, the $m_x$-adic topology of $A^{\prime}_{m_x}$ coincides with the $m_{\varphi(x)}$-adic one, when $A^{\prime}_{m_x}$ is viewed as an $A_{m_{\varphi(x)}}$-module via $\varphi^{*}_{m_x}$. Now it is claimed further that by Krull's intersection theorem, $\operatorname{im} \varphi^{*}_{m_x}$ is a closed submodule of $A^{\prime}_{m_x}$. I do not understand this last claim. How can one deduce the closedness from Krull's intersection theorem? Is it a general statement or is it only true in this special case?

Answer (score 2):

I was just having the same problem while studying this book, but I think I have a solution. It is essential to use the hypothesis that $\varphi_{m_x}^*$ is finite is this situation, which you do not mention in your question.

Let us set the notation $N:=\text{Im}\,\varphi_{m_x}^*$ and $\bar{N}$ for its $m_{\varphi(x)}$-adic (same as $m_x$-adic) closure in $A'_{m_x}$. Also, denote the quotient of $A_{m_{\varphi(x)}}$-modules $A'_{m_x}/N$ by $P$.

Using the finiteness hypothesis, we see that $P$ is a finitely generated $A_{m_{\varphi(x)}}$-module. Its $m_{\varphi(x)}$-adic topology is generated by $P_n:=m_{\varphi(x)}^n P$. Applying Krull's Intersection Thm. and then Nakayama's Lemma we find that $\bigcap_nP_n=\{0\}$.

Now, if $a'\in\bar{N}$, then $a'\in\bigcap_n(N+m_{\varphi(x)}^nA_{m_x}')$, which means that the image of $a'$ in $P$ is actually in $\bigcap_n P_n$. But the latter infinite intersection being trivial, we conclude that $a'\in N$, thus $N$ is closed.